# How to get value of parent node as string?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase image]

So in the above data structure, I want to get value `Aprilia Caponord 1200` (marked in fig.). I have Firebase reference to `Aprilia` (root node) and I can get all the key/value pair data.

Here's my code

```
@override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChild()) {
    Map<?, ?> value = (Map<?, ?>) child.getValue();
    String bike_price = value.get("price").toString();
    String image_url = value.get("image_url").toString();
    }
}
```

So clearly I can get all the values of child nodes having key/value relations. But I can't specifically get the name of the parent node. So how can I get the value of parent node in `String` format?

If I print `child.getValue().toString()`, I get JSON value, but I am not interested in parsing JSON. Is there any specific way to get parent node value?

```
{Aprilia Caponord 1200={image_url=____________, price=18.35}.. }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `getKey()` method on `DataSnapshot`:

```
    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com");
    mFirebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", child.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "onCancelled", firebaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

A few things to note here:

- I changed `getChild()` in your code to `getChildren()`, since there is not method `getChild()` that I'm aware of.
- You should consider using `addChildEventListener`, which gives you `DataSnapshots` on the lower-level nodes
- Things will get considerably easier if you create "wrapper classes" for your cars. The Firebase SDK for Android will then automagically unwrap the JSON into instances of that class. See our [AndroidChat repo](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/androidchat) for a good example of this.

Answer (score 0):

I met this case and solved the way as below:

```
final ChildEventListener countsListener = new ChildEventListener() { //for querying how many card created by each user in a specific period
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                /**
                 * $ROOT/Apirilia/Apirilia_id/CardId/IMG_URL
                 * $ROOT/Apirilia/Apirilia_id/CardId/PRICE
                 *                      ^[key] :[value]
                 */
                if (dataSnapshot == null) {
                    Logger.e("!!! dataSnapshot is null");
                    return;
                }
                String apirilia_id = dataSnapshot.getRef().getParent().getKey();
                Logger.d("... Apirilia_id:" + apirilia_id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
```

I'm appreciated to be able to give one a hand.

Answer (score 0):

for those who looking for key in firebaseUi then this code will work for u:-

`firebaseadapterinstance.getRef(position).getKey();`