# How to iterate over a Datasnapshot without specifying parent folder/ref

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to iterate through a Data snapshot with the following structure;

```
 {
"data" : {
"images" : {
  "fw88v6xu6wybamg9zzt6" : {
    "0550e909-3b30-4f83-9725-02fbe45b74ce" : 3,
    "address" : "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg",
    "author" : "username1",
    "author_id" : "0550e909-3b30-4f83-9725-02fbe45b74ce",
    "location" : "0",
    "rating" : 3
  },
  "osgm6v7kfcjwogo5uv21" : {
    "0550e909-3b30-4f83-9725-02fbe45b74ce" : 4,
    "address" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg",
    "author" : "username1",
    "author_id" : "0550e909-3b30-4f83-9725-02fbe45b74ce",
    "location" : "0",
    "rating" : 4
  },
  "prhpcbrrru7z8x6xtolq" : {
    "0550e909-3b30-4f83-9725-02fbe45b74ce" : 6,
    "address" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg",
    "author" : "username2",
    "author_id" : "0550e909-3b30-4f83-9725-02fbe45b74ce",
    "location" : 0,
    "rating" : 6
  }
},
"locations" : {
  "location1" : {
    "author" : "0550e909-3b30-4f83-9725-02fbe45b74ce",
    "latitude" : 11.42222573,
    "longitude" : 58.4348011
  },
  "location2" : {
    "author" : "0550e909-3b30-4f83-9725-02fbe45b74ce",
    "latitude" : 11.42222573,
    "longitude" : 38.4333311
  }
 }
}
```

Specifically what I am doing is getting a snapshot of Data/Images children, so it would be the three entries with the auto generated references such as `fw88v6xu6wybamg9zzt6`
thus I can not accesses a specific entry to retrieve the address for example of the author, so I made my app get

```
    Iterable<DataSnapshot> imagesDir = snapshot.getChildren();
```

and I am not sure how to go over each entry of this snapshot and retrieve the information for entry without knowing the parent ref. ( `fw88v6xu6wybamg9zzt6` ) ?

All right well, I got to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669363/firebase-how-get-to-value-of-parent-node-as-string)

Thankx to Chris, for sending me on the right path to search for it, but still not able to construct the right syntax to reach what I am trying to do.

For now my method is as follow;

```
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("MyTag", child.getValue().toString());
                imagesDir.add(String.valueOf(child.getValue()));
            }
            Log.i("MyTag", imagesDir.toString());
```

from the first Log I get a string of all the values for each node, and on the second one I constructed an array to include all the nodes.

What i am trying to do is add a specific node ( e.g. address Value) to an ArrayList I declared outside the `onDataChange` method, everytime it iterates over a child. so by the end of the for loop, I would have three addresses in the arraylist (only the values) in this case.

What is the proper way to construct a for loop in order to do that?

Well, the final code I got to and gave me the right outcome is as following;

```
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("MyTag", child.getValue().toString());
                imagesDir.add(child.child("author").getValue(String.class));
            }
            Log.i("MyTag_imagesDirFinal", imagesDir.toString());
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you attach a `ValueEventListener` to `images`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot imagesSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot imageSnapshot: imagesSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        imagesDir.add(imageSnapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class));
    }
    Log.i("MyTag", imagesDir.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have a better understanding of it right now, although i must say that i faced a tiny problem, declaring Datasnapshot as imagesSnapshot as you did in the for loop, which is less confusing than what i did initially using "child" but understood how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you retrieve the snapshot of "images", you can access the getChildren() method to iterate through each image, even without knowing the keys.

If needed, they keys can be accessed by calling getKey() on the child.

Reference to the getChildren() method can be found in the Reference Docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#public-methods

Comment: Thank you @Chris_Conway , you got me on the right direction to understand the way this works, and with the help of some search i reached this post similar to mine but still not able to construct the right syntax to achieve what i am trying to do, as you could see in my updated post

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tried `for (DataSnapshot child : parent.getChildren()) { ... }` ? `child.key` should return your `fw88...` key for one of those child objects.