# Fetching data one by one from Datasnapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an app in Android Studio and linked with Real-time Database of Firebase. I have a table named [Attendance Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxuLt.png) in my database, in which the first key is employee ID, the second key is month, then date and then the details of that employee's attendance of that date.

I basically have to let the user view his attendance and his attendance record should have the rows of that date colored on which it was a holiday.

I have an activity in which user enters his empid along with year and month and then a table should be displayed with same column names as the details under the date key. I can do this by directly displaying the data snapshot but it can't be modified. I need to modify it in the way that I access another table [Holidays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUhcq.png) and compare the dates mentioned in 'Holidays' table and the data snapshot of the specific user and color those rows (for which date exits in both tables) in the dynamically created table.

I am referring to https://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/ for dynamically creating the table.

How can I get values from the data snapshot one by one and put them in the while loop to enter them in the table rows which are being dynamically created?

Comment: To iterate over the `DataSnapShot` [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37508782/5482999) link should help you.
While iterating over the items add them to an ArrayList so you can populate your table.
Personally I would go for a RecyclerView Firebase has its own RecyclerAdapter.

Comment: What difference will recyclerview make?

Comment: Recyclerview is optimized for that kind of operations. However if your data is not meant to grow maybe you just use a tablelayout, I think that it will depend how you want to manipulate the data you are populating and how you are tackling your problem.

Comment: Alright and can you tell me how can I color specific rows(for dates which exist in both the tables) ?

Comment: If you will go for the Recyclerview approach, you'll do it in your adapter in onbindviewholder.

Comment: And what if I want to use Table Layout? Is there any method to color rows in this?

Comment: Using an adapter to populate the table.

Comment: RecyclerView seems more promising, so, if I use RecyclerView  I will still have to fetch data from Firebase by Datasnapshot and iterate through it and serially store in the RecyclerView? I am new to RecyclerView please guide.

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/Vyqz_-sJGFk) video should get you started, he is very clear and understandable. Good luck .

Comment: Okay! Thankyou so much! You helped a lot! :)

Comment: @Racu Hey! Unfortunately I am unable to post questions, but I wanted to ask one, I want to check if the date(I have in a variable) is a Sunday or not, how can I do this? Please guide..

Comment: I think it will depend on the format of your date, e.g.:

`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2018, 3, 18);
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));`
Note that here the date is April, 18, 2018, which returns a "4" corresponding to WEDNESDAY

Comment: Oh okay great, and can you also tell me in which format should I get the date from the user(and save in the database)?

Comment: @Racu If I have entered 10 dates in my Firebase database using date picker in one activity and then in another activity I want to use your code of Calendar class then for that, how can I break the date string into year, month and day?

Comment: How are you storing your date?
Milliseconds long?
String?
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12473614/5482999) helps you

Comment: or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655033/5482999)

Comment: @Racu great! Thanks! Just one more thing, for reading from Firebase I am using addListenerForSingleValueEvent in onBindViewHolder and then doing my if-else statements for coloring the cardview, the issue is, I have 2 dates for 2 different cases and both of those cases(if-elseif) are being reached in code, but only the first cardView's color is changing, is it because of the addListenerForSingleValueEvent? Should I use any other listener? If I use addChildEventListener then should I enter my if-else statements in onChildAdded or what? Please help :/

Comment: Man it depends on what you want to achieve. The way I see it having your listener in onbindviewholder, not a good idea. It's hard to “advise" without seeing code. Maybe it would be OK to have the listener there. The color change has nothing to do with your listener. If your data is not going to change use the singleValueEvent...

Comment: Okay, I'll look to it, Thanks!

Comment: What you might wanna do if the color change is supposed to happen when the Recyclerview is attached is to notifyDataSetChange() or notifyItemChanged(int position).

Comment: @Racu I have posted the code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774931/only-first-cardview-of-recyclerview-is-being-colored

Please have a look! :)