# Only first CardView of RecyclerView is being Colored

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have created an app in Android Studio, using CardViews in RecyclerView in connection with Firebase Realtime database, in which user can check his attendance such that if the user came on a holiday(R,G, Saturday or Sunday) that CardView is colored. But in my code only the first CardView is getting colored. I have checked through Log statements that it's traversing through both R and G's if-else statements.

My code is:

```
public class frag2ofAttendanceNew extends Fragment {

String mPinFromFrag1ofAttendance;
String yearf1;
String monthf1;


private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
DatabaseReference myRef;
DatabaseReference holidaysRef;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Log.d("abcd","oncreate view reached");
    final View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag2of_attendance_new, container, false);
    Log.d("abcd","oncreate view reached and layout inflated");
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("abcd","onstart reached");
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    if(b!=null){
        mPinFromFrag1ofAttendance = b.getString("mPinToFrag2ofAttendance");
        Log.d("abcd","Receiving from frag1ofAttendance");
        yearf1 = b.getString("year");
        monthf1 = b.getString("month");
    }
    Log.d("abcd",mPinFromFrag1ofAttendance);
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Attendance_Records").child(mPinFromFrag1ofAttendance).child(yearf1).child(monthf1);

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    Log.d("abcd","setlayoutmanager");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Attendance_Records>().setQuery(myRef,Attendance_Records.class).build();
    Log.d("abcd","recycleroptions reached");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Attendance_Records,AttendanceViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Attendance_Records, AttendanceViewHolder>
                    (options) {

            @NonNull
                @Override
                public AttendanceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    Log.d("abcd","oncreateviewholder reached");
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
                    Log.d("abcd","cardview inflated");
                    return new AttendanceViewHolder(view);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(AttendanceViewHolder holder, int position, Attendance_Records model) {

                    holidaysRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Holidays");
                    final String userdate = model.getDate();

                    try {
                        Log.d("abcd","StringTodate about to be called");
                        StringToDate(userdate);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    holidaysRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.child(userdate).exists()){
                                Log.d("abcd","date matched");
                       final DatabaseReference tilldateRef = holidaysRef.child(userdate);
                                tilldateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                                        if(dataSnapshot1.child("G").exists()){
                                            Log.d("abcd","its G");
                                            CardView cv = getView().findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                                            Log.d("abcd","cardview found");
                                            cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                                            Log.d("abcd","changed cv color");
                                        }
                                        else if(dataSnapshot1.child("R").exists()){
                                            Log.d("abcd","its R");
                                            CardView cv = getView().findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                                            Log.d("abcd","cardview found");
                                            cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                                            Log.d("abcd","changed cv color");
                                        }
                                        else if(day==7){
                                            Log.d("abcd","its Saturday");
                                            CardView cv = getView().findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                                            Log.d("abcd","cardview found");
                                            cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                            Log.d("abcd","changed cv color");
                                        }
                                        else if(day==1){
                                            Log.d("abcd","its Sunday");
                                            CardView cv = getView().findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                                            Log.d("abcd","cardview found");
                                            cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                                            Log.d("abcd","changed cv color");
                                        }


                                        else{
                                            Log.d("abcd","None from G,R or Weekend");
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    holder.setYear(model.getYear());
                    holder.setMonth(model.getMonth());
                    holder.setDate(model.getDate());
                    holder.setIntime(model.getInTime());
                    holder.setOuttime(model.getOutTime());
                    holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
                    holder.setEntrydate(model.getEntryDate());
                    holder.setMyid(model.getMyID());
                    Log.d("abcd","onbindviewholder reached");
                }
    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();

}

private void StringToDate(String date) throws ParseException{
    Log.d("abcd","StringtoDate reached");
    DateFormat formatter = null;
    Date convertedDate = null;

    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    convertedDate = (Date)formatter.parse(date);
    Log.d("abcd","date converted");

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.d("abcd","Calendar getInstance reached");
    c.setTime(convertedDate);
    Log.d("abcd","userdate set in Calendar");
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    Log.d("abcd","day of week is "+day);
}

public class AttendanceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView vhyear, vhmonth, vhdate, vhintime, vhouttime, vhentrydate, vhstatus, vhmyid;
    public AttendanceViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        Log.d("abcd","attendanceviewholder reached");
        vhyear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.year);
        vhmonth = itemView.findViewById(R.id.month);
        vhdate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        vhintime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inTime);
        vhouttime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.outTime);
        vhentrydate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.entryDate);
        vhstatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        vhmyid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userId);
        Log.d("abcd","textviews found");

    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        Log.d("abcd","setyear reached");
        vhyear.setText(year);
        Log.d("abcd",vhyear.getText().toString());
    }

    public void setMonth(String month) {
        Log.d("abcd","setmonth reached");
        vhmonth.setText(month);
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Log.d("abcd","setdate reached");
        vhdate.setText(date);
    }

    public void setIntime(String inTime) {
        Log.d("abcd","setintime reached");
        vhintime.setText(inTime);
    }

    public void setOuttime(String outTime) {
        Log.d("abcd","setouttime reached");
        vhouttime.setText(outTime);
    }

    public void setEntrydate(String entrydate){
        Log.d("abcd","setentrydate reached");
        vhentrydate.setText(entrydate);
    }

    public void setStatus(String status){
        Log.d("abcd","setstatus reached");
        vhstatus.setText(status);
    }

    public void setMyid(String myid){
        Log.d("abcd","setmyid reached");
        vhmyid.setText(myid);
    }
}

}
```

[My Attendance_Records table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6C6K.png)

[My Holidays Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2QsG.png)

**UPDATE**

I have achieved for holidays in holidays table but still not able to color the weekends. Should I put those conditions somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the CardView in the ViewHolder:

```
    CardView cv;

        public AttendanceViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
                Log.d("abcd","attendanceviewholder reached");
                vhyear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.year);
                cv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    ...
        }
```

Then use

```
holder.cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

instead of

```
CardView cv = getView().findViewById(R.id.card_view);
Log.d("abcd","cardview found");
cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! The R and G holidays are getting colored, but weekends aren't getting colored or even checked, should I put those condition somewhere else?

Comment: No, the program doesn't reach them

Comment: d you see the "day of week is ---" log?

Comment: Yes, and can you tell me if I am using the right day no. for saturday and sunday?

Comment: It's preferable to use Calendar.SUNDAY, Calendar.SATURDAY etc. but it seems that the numbers are correct, check your database

Comment: I got it! Had to define the 'weekends' if-else separately.