# Going to parent of an entry in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attaching a picture [image: Database]  of my firebase database. I am at OPL and I want to go to its parent. Is there somekind of "GetParent()" kind of fuction, like "GetChildren" that can take me there?

Comment: All that should be needed is calling [`DatabaseReference.getParent()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#getParent()). If you have a problem with getting your code to do what you want, can you show the [minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That will make it a lot easier to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase - How get to value of parent node as string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669363/firebase-how-get-to-value-of-parent-node-as-string)

Answer (score 0):

To read the data from database, you need to set listeners at appropriate locations. These listeners provide values for one time as well as for updates with the methods `onChildAdded()` and `onChildChanged()`.

For your case, you should attach a childListener on the `ActionList` by using the line
`mDatabase.child('ActionList').addChildEventListener(listenerName);`
Set up the `onChildAdded()` method of this listener which provides a snapshot. Traversing through the children from that snapshot using `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` and to get their values use this function `child.getKey()` method.