# How to retrieve parent key in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve `houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2` key , How to do?

Here is the code for the same

```
mQuery = mfollowing.orderByChild("following").equalTo(user_id);
mQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        final String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

        mdatabaseUsers.child(user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                DatabaseReference newfollscreen = mdatabaseFollwer.child(key).child(newPost.getKey());

                newfollscreen.child("screen").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                newfollscreen.child("engagement").setValue("NA");
                newfollscreen.child("url").setValue("NA");
                newfollscreen.child("uid").setValue(user_id);
                newfollscreen.child("name").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue());
                newfollscreen.child("image").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                            Toast.makeText(AddimageActivity.this, "Posted among your followers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {

                            Toast.makeText(AddimageActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError
       databaseError){

    }

});
```

Here is the Firebase database

[image: Here is the Firebase database]

**second image**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8PNW.png)

I tried using child data snapshot method but did not worked. Any help for this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what you've tried already.

Comment: I shared my code, please have a look. Thankyou

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the key name as string (you have used `getKey()` which will do that) or are you trying to access the parent node as a list?

Comment: I want to access parent node which is a key of some other user.

Comment: As in [working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) or more like [how to get value of parent node as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669363/firebase-how-get-to-value-of-parent-node-as-string)? Also, your code is nesting multiple event listeners, does it work as is? What is your end goal?

Comment: Yeah its working . I want to upload data at multiple locations with single process.

Comment: I recommend you to check DatabaseReference variable and use debug mode to see what key you are getting at this moment, because `String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();` should give you key.

Comment: I m getting "Following" as the key which the Database Folder under which I have stored all this. I guess, I should try to make String key = datasnapshot.child.getkey(); just read about it somewhere on other answers.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, I did solved it. if you dint solved it till now, let me know, will send you code to understand.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: @AlexMamo which answer are you talking about? Or this is your other account? Because with this name i dint found answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `DataSnapshot` that points to the children `rhZ4...wt2`, you can call `snapsthot.getRef().toString()` which will return you something like `https://xxx.firebaseio.com/.../houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2/rhZ4...wt2`. From there you can extract the parent key.

From your example, after you query the database using `mQuery`, inside `onDataChange` you have a `DataSnapshot`.

So calling `dataSnapshot.getRef().toString()` will give you `https://xxx.firebaseio.com/.../houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2/rhZ4...wt2/following`.

Code to extract the parent key (put it inside your 1st `onDataChange`):

```
String reference = dataSnapshot.getRef().toString();
String[] tokens = reference.split("/");
String parentKey = tokens[tokens.length - 3];
```

This `parentKey` should be your `houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2`.

Comment: @PuneetTawniya Sure I can, can you let me know which variable denotes the key houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2 in your code?

Comment: you mean to ask which database reference connects us with this key (houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2) ?

Comment: I meant what variable in your code refers to this key houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2? Is it "mfollowing"?

Comment: actually it don't have any variable because I need to find that key.

Comment: but once I get it, I named it with "String Key = data snapshot.getKey()";

Comment: wait, I ll add one more image

Comment: mfollowing will make you reach till "Following" database, you can look into another image I uploaded, the key which we are talking about is not known to us but we know the child of the "following" present along with username and userimage. Did you got?

Comment: Go it, OK then which variable are you using to reach "following"?

Comment: mQuery as a query to reach to following because key (rhZ4RkttsUeUi2CdiCPGtcqRlwt2) is known.

Comment: .getString() in code is throwing error, any idea about this?

Comment: @PuneetTawniya sorry it should be toString(), updated my answer. My bad.