# How do I get immediate parent keys in firebase

Tags: java, android, database, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

So I am trying to get immediate parent keys which are actually children under 'users' database.

Like so, the underlines ones -

[image]

My code for the same is as follows -

```
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            for( DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String  user = postSnapshot.getKey();
                list.add(user);

            }

        }
```

But all it is doing is returning the below image -

[image]

Comment: Please log the user.

Comment: On the contrary logged in user does not have to be shown in the list. Rest other users have to be shown. have found something over here but regex is returning weird data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949464/how-to-retrieve-parent-key-in-firebase-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First your database reference must be like this:**

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
```

**This is how you read the data:**

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      String  user = ds.getKey();
      list.add(user);

    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //log error
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }
};
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Comment: You have just written same code as mine which is returning username and password like the second image posted in the question

Comment: this is a ValueEvent listener not a child listener.

Comment: and the database reference?

Comment: Sorry I had missed the last line...It worked..thank you..have accepted your answer..